# Libfdx - how to save memory changing screen

Tags: java, memory, libgdx, screen, heap-memory

My problem is the following, by monitoring my application with android studio I see a part of memory consumed every time I change screen. This should be normal since it is instantiating new stuff, but even if I call all the dispose methods and eliminate my objects this memory never comes back. So after a few times that I call my screen the memory crashes (it is a game where after every game over it calls the same screen back). How can I change screen properly cleaning the memory I used? I'm just using bodies, sprites and some sound. Everything is disposed.

Comment: Sounds like your missing a dispose somewhere

Comment: If its always the same screen. Do you need to create a new one each time? You can just keep it and just reuse the same object with the setScreen.

Comment: That is true, but I would like to understand the problem. For example I have the same leak of memory when I go from my menu screen to the game screen.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can better understand the situation. I can speculate that you are recreating the screen multiple times ? Without code it's hard to guess...